# Is there a default buffer length for 'sprintf' method?

Tags: visual-c++, printf, buffer-overflow, access-violation

I used sprintf method to format data to a string which I want to write to a file, in C++ console application using VS 2008. The Input is a particular message, which has various variables and values (ex: Type 'int' and Value '10' / Type string and value "abc", etc.) When I send a two messages it works perfectly. But When I send more than two messages it gives a runtime error saying **0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xabababab**. Why is this happening? Is it because the method 'sprintf' has a default buffer length? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to show us the actual code, your explanation is not clear (enough).

Comment: Since this doesn't have a `C` tag, but has a tag with a `C++` in it, have you considered using string streams instead? It's much harder to get an AV with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no default size. It will assume that there is space enough, and write as much as specified by the formatting string.

Your access violation says *reading*, which hints that there might be something wrong with your arguments, perhaps they don't match the formatting string.

You need to have exactly as many arguments, of the proper types and in the correct order, as you reference using `%`-codes in the formatting string.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you might want to have a look at [this page](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Magic%20number%20%28programming%29).

> 0xABABABAB : Used by Microsoft's HeapAlloc() to mark "no man's land" guard bytes  after allocated heap memory